# I cound not able to install monodevelop in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, binary, mono, monodevelop, lib

I want to install Monodevelop in ubuntu for that I follow instruction provided on http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin
[image: provided repository for ubuntu 14.04]

After following these following.
I put command `sudo apt-get install mono-complete monodevelop`

But unmet dependencies are as follows.

[image: dependencies error]

Please help me to get resolve the issue..

Thanks very much..

Comment: Along with tit there is an issue that I could not upgrade my operating system due to some issue related to Graphics driver (amd)

Answer (score 0):

The unmet condition is by design. The `monodevelop` package is too old, so it does not work with latest Mono (5.x) packages.

You can now use the alternative installer from GitHub,

https://github.com/cra0zy/monodevelop-run-installer

I have a blog post to cover more details,

https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1

Comment: There is 10 error during build in Ubuntu 14.04 Kernel 3.16.